# active_model_serializer: How to test in the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

How can I check the serialization of an active model serializer in the command line?

```
$ rails c
> ModelSerializer.new(Model.last)
=> # does not give me the custom format of my serializer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the call to `to_json`.

```
ModelSerializer.new(Model.last).to_json
```

to properly view it in `irb` use `puts`

```
puts ModelSerializer.new(Model.last).to_json
```

You can also use `as_json` or `serializable_attributes` to get the attributes as `Hash`. Not surprisingly, these methods use the same naming of the built-in serialization methods in an `ActiveRecord` model.

Comment: Thanks @simone, I had missed that. Do you know of any methods added directly to the model that would produce the same output? e.g. Model.last.serialized_json ?

Comment: Please beware that the method `to_json` from the model is not the same of `to_json` from a serializer object. In fact, the purpose of the serializer is to avoid using those model built-in serialization methods that are not a good practice.

Comment: What if you need to pass a `serialization_scope` to the serializer? In a controller, the serializer is given `current_user`, but I cannot figure out how to provide a scope in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are using AMS version 0.10.x, you need to do the following to get the hash from outside a Rails controller:

```
ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(Model.last).serializable_hash
```